# Excel: Count colors in a personnel schedule

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

This is driving me nuts. Please help.

I have a personnel spreadsheet. Names on the Y-axis (column A). Column B reflects each employees' work category (text field). Day of the month across the top on the X-axix (columns C-W). Employee activity for each day is reflected by the background color of the cell representing the day of the month. If sick days are reflected with a red background color, how do I count the number of red cells, broken down by each work category (reflected in the values in column B)?

Comment: Instead of changing the background colour of the cell to signify sick days, why not put a value in the cell and use conditional formatting to colour the cell?  For example, you could put the word "sick" into the cell, and have a condition to make these cells red text on red background.  That means you could just count the "sick"s.  The appearance is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula in Excel to read the color of a cell,

```
=CELL("color",A1)
```

unfortunately, it only gives you 0 or 1, depending on the color being the 'negative-value-color' or not. If your color (red) happens to be that 'negative-value-color', or if you can adjust that setting accordingly, you can use something like

```
=SUM(CELL("color",$C2:$W2))
```

(matrix formula, use < CTRL > + < SHIFT > + < RET > when entering)

and it gives you the number of colored cells. If your color is not Excel's 'negative-value-color', it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
Dim datax As range
Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
    CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
End If
Next datax
End Function
```

[Click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2815384) to know how to use the above function.